# ios UIButton subclass to reuse button in Storyboard

Tags: ios6, uibutton, subclass

I have created an app which uses the storyboard feature in Xcode.

I need to put a button on a few views which is a "Call us" button. The button will have the same look, text and action associated with it.

It's that reason which I thought would be best to create a subclass of the button and set all the button properties from there.

There are no coding problems, but when I drag on a button to a view on the storyboard, change it's class to the "CallButton" subclass name - it simply ignores all the formatting.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to reuse a button? Normally (old school way) I would simply call the button from the code, but as I've used the storyboard, I need to drag and drop the button really.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is your button type set to anything other `UIButtonTypeCustom` in the storyboard? Also, which initializer did you override in the `UIButton` subclass?

Comment: Yes it's set to UIButtonTypeCustom and I've overwritten both the initWithFrame and initWithCoder methods. It does work at run time, but I wanted to see it in the designer. Just wondered if I was missing something!

Answer (score 2):

Xcode wont reflect the changes you make programatically in your subclass, but if you're setting up the buttons look in your subclass it should look as expected when you run the application.

Ideally you would setup your CustomButton in its initWithFrame and initWithCoder methods.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: Thanks I feared it might be that. It does work at run-time, but it's difficult to design the button when I cannot see how it should look in the storyboard designer! Maybe I just have to live with it?!

Comment: IB isn't that advanced, sorry!

Comment: darn. I've had to call the custom button, but add a background to each one in IB so I can check it's position... then check it's ok when I run on a device!

Comment: As an update, you can now see certain changes if they're marked IBInspectable: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html